# In XSLT/XQuery regex, is there a required order for evaluation of alternated expressions?

Tags: regex, xslt, xpath, xquery

Most explanations of regex generally seem to suggest that the expected behavior is to use greedy evaluation of expressions *from left to right*. However, in one XQuery implementation, I found that alternated expressions are evaluated in parallel (evidently for performance), which means the "first" match will not necessarily be the first *from the left* to match.

For example, in every other XQuery processor I've tested, given this input:

```
fn:analyze-string(  
  '1-a. x. y. z.', 
  '^(\d+[-\w]*\.?|.{1,10}\.)\s(.+)$',
  'ix')
```

The same output is returned:

```
<analyze-string-result>
   <match>
      <group nr="1">1-a.</group> 
      <group nr="2">x. y. z.</group>
   </match>
</analyze-string-result>
```

However, there is one XQuery processor that (in group 1) evaluates the second expression before the first, and it matches instead:

```
<analyze-string-result>
  <match>
    <group nr="1">1-a. x. y.</group>
    <group nr="2">z.</group>
  </match>
</analyze-string-result>
```

Is there any interpretation of the regex specification for XQuery where the latter result would be considered valid?

Comment: Best practice is to avoid using branches that match at the same location. BTW, what is the XQuery processor that uses POSIX way of handling alternations (that second one)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Without lookarounds that's very hard to do for the input I have to deal with. I may be forced to refactor the expression into a much larger one or break it into stages to enforce priority. This is on MarkLogic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-analyze-string saying

> If several alternatives within the regular expression both match at
>   the same position in the input string, then the match that is chosen
>   is the first alternative that matches. For example, if the input
>   string is `The quick brown fox jumps` and the regular expression is
>   `jump|jumps`, then the match that is chosen is `jump`.

I think that the first result you posted is the correct one, the other processor producing the second result has a bug.

Comment: The second result is just POSIX compliant where the longest branch "wins".

Comment: Many XSLT and XQuery implementations use an off-the-shelf regex library and this often results in non-conformant behaviour, sadly.